# javascript not working, working on fiddle but not on my webserver

Tags: javascript, html

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <script> 


  var timer = document.getElementById("logout-timer")  
    , now = new Date()  
    , deadline = new Date(now.getFullYear, now.getMonth, now.getDate, now.getHours, now.getMinutes + 15);  

  timer.innerHTML = countdown(deadline).toString();  
  setInterval(function(){  
    timer.innerHTML = countdown(deadline ).toString();  
  }, 1000);  


    </script> 

    You will be logged out in <span id="logout-timer"></span>  
    </body>
    </html>
```

I have this script that works on fiddle.js but when i implement it into my website ^ like that it doesnt work why?

Comment: In what way does it fail? "Doesn't work" is a too vague description.

Comment: is your website on your local computer?

Comment: Where are you defining `countdown`?

Comment: It doesnt display the countdown timer, it's not hosted on local computer

Comment: Also see [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as getElementById not find the element?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14028959/218196)

Answer (score 3):

Move the `script` to after the `span`, or wrap the code in a function and call it when the `ready` or `load` event fires.

`document.getElementById("logout-timer")` can't find the `span` before it exists.

---

You also need to define `countdown`; there is no sign of it in your code.

Comment: Tried that, no change

Comment: This is almost always the reason for something working in a fiddle (which defaults -- bizarrely -- to using onload) and not working otherwise.

Comment: Why does this work on fiddle, and why the deleted answer was wrong?

Comment: @VLAS: It's perfectly valid to leave off the protocol. It's a relative URL, relative to the protocol used to load the page. More: http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2011/01/skipping-protocol.html

Comment: @VLAS — It works on the fiddle because, as TJ mentioned, it wraps the JS in a function and calls it on load. The deleted answer was wrong because (a) it failed to fix the problem described in this answer and (b) made some assumptions (that your HTML document was being loaded using a `file://` URI) that the subject of your question showed were wrong.